# Problem of how to link input from a form to a variable PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am new on Python and PyQt5.
I used Qt Design to create a form for input.
I am able to print the 3 data that the user input but I don't know how to store them in a variable so that I can use them in the main program.

```
import PyQt5 as pq
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtGui

def Assigned(self):
    
    Nx=call.Nx11.text()
    Ny=call.Ny11.text()
    Nxy=call.Nxy11.text()
    Mx=call.Mx11.text()
    My=call.My11.text()
    Mxy=call.Mxy11.text()
    print(Nx)
    print(Ny)
    print(Nxy)
    return(Nx)
    return(Ny)
    return(Nxy)
   
app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
call=pq.uic.loadUi("InputLoad.ui")

call.OKbutton.clicked.connect(Assigned)

call.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: 1]

Thank you in advance for any help.
Fab

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and add the module ʻInputLoad.ui`

Answer (score -1):

Create a global variable and store them

```
import PyQt5 as pq
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtGui

Nx = None
Ny = None
Nxy = None
def Assigned(self):
    global Nx, Ny, Nxy
    Nx=call.Nx11.text()
    Ny=call.Ny11.text()
    Nxy=call.Nxy11.text()
    Mx=call.Mx11.text()
    My=call.My11.text()
    Mxy=call.Mxy11.text()
    print(Nx)
    print(Ny)
    print(Nxy)
   
app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
call=pq.uic.loadUi("InputLoad.ui")

call.OKbutton.clicked.connect(Assigned)

call.show()
app.exec_()
```